# How to check if a string contains all of the characters of another string?

Tags: c++

If I have two strings, `string str` and `string prt`. I want to check if `str` contains the characters of `prt` *irrespective* of their indexes. Meaning, no matter how characters are arranged in `prt`, if `str` contains all of the characters of `ptr`, then `str` contains `ptr`.

For example:

```
str="Pegasus"
prt="eas"
```

This should output `true` because `str` contains each character that `prt` has.

Is there any pre-defined function to achieve this task?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Looks like the OP is looking to find a subset of characters, and not a substring.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not this one , If str=", Pegasus" and prt="eas" ,Then it would print false because Pegasus doesn't contain eas in sequence.

Comment: Ah, I see. No, there's no predefined function then.

Comment: I've reopened it. I suggest changing the title to not say "portion of string", I got confused by it too.

Comment: Simplest way is probably to just count the number of each characters in str. Then you count the number of each character in prt. Then you have an if statement checking for all of those countA,countB,...,countZ variables that make sure str is > prt.

Comment: try something, there is nothing fundamentaly hard about this. if you get stuck post the code you have so far and explain what problem you have

Comment: Is order important? I.e., if str=`abc` and prt=`ca`, is the answer true or false? What about duplicated letters? I.e., if str=`abc` and prt=`bb`, is the answer true or false?

Comment: Which charset? UTF-8?

Comment: If the second string contains a character twice, should it appear twice?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any pre-defined function to achieve this task?

No. Since that's the only actual question in your question, I'm tempted to stop there.

We can write many different functions to do this - which ones are a good choice depend on things like how long your strings are, how much time you can justify spending on this, how important its performance is to your program, etc. etc.

The closest to a pre-defined function we can get is a (long) oneliner, like

```
bool contained = std::ranges::includes(std::set<char>{str.begin(), str.end()},
                                       std::set<char>{prt.begin(), prt.end()});
```

It requires C++20 [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/includes), and creates a couple of temporary sets, each containing every unique letter in one of the strings.

If you don't have C++20 support or don't need it to fit on one line, you can easily materialize those temporary sets as in Remy's answer, and call the older [`std::includes`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes) (although that's still preferable to using `set_intersection` here).

There's an un-answered question in comments about repeated characters: this doesn't check whether `str` contains at least as many of each distinct character as `prt` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to determine whether a string contains a specific character.

Therefore, in order to determine whether `str` contains all characters in `ptr`, you can call `std::string::find` once for every character in `ptr`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool contains_all_characters( const std::string &str, const std::string &prt )
{
    for ( char c : prt )
    {
        if ( str.find( c ) == std::string::npos )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str, prt;

    std::cout << "Enter string: ";
    std::getline( std::cin, str );

    std::cout << "Enter part: ";
    std::getline( std::cin, prt );

    if ( contains_all_characters( str, prt ) )
        std::cout << "Does contain all characters.\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Does NOT contain all characters.\n";
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Enter string: Pegasus
Enter part: eas
Does contain all characters.
```

```
Enter string: Pegasus
Enter part: eat
Does NOT contain all characters.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `std::sort()` the strings, and then use `std::set_intersection()` to check if the result (the characters present in both strings) exactly equals the 2nd string, eg:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

bool containsPrt(std::string str, std::string prt)
{
    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
    std::sort(prt.begin(), prt.end());
    std::string result;
    std::set_intersection(
        str.begin(), str.end(), prt.begin(), prt.end(),
        std::back_inserter(result));
    return result == prt;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/SMNkRM)

Alternatively, you can use `std::set` to collect the characters ignoring any duplicates, and then check the intersection of the `set`s, eg:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

bool containsPrt(const std::string &str, const std::string &prt)
{
    std::set<char> s1(str.begin(), str.end());
    std::set<char> s2(prt.begin(), prt.end());
    std::set<char> result;
    std::set_intersection(
        s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),
        std::inserter(result, result.begin()));
    return result == s2;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/FgeKuu)